# rails db:migrate NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a view that I did the migration on development and then production fine.
I then set up another development box and dont seem to be able to run the migration, I get
`'NameError: uninitialized constant ChangeUpcomingEventsView'`.

```
class UpcommingEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    self.connection.execute %Q( CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW upcoming_events AS
       SELECT   v.name                                  "venue_name",
                to_char(e.start_date,'Day (DD Mon)')    "day",
                to_char(e.start_date,'Dy')              "day",
                to_char(e.start_time,'HH24:MI')         "time",
                e.title                                 "event_name",
                e.description                           "event_description",
                e.price,
                e.url,
                url_ticket
        FROM    events e,
                venues v
        WHERE   v.id = e.venue_id
        AND     e.status = 'L'
        AND     e.start_date
        BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE)::date
        AND     (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '7 day')::date
        order by start_date, e.start_time, replace(v.name,'The ','')
    )
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP VIEW upcoming_events"
  end
end
```

My ruby version is `2.4.1` and my rails version is `5.1.3`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the content of `db/migrate/` forlder?

Comment: Can you share the migration of event table, also share both models.

Comment: I don't think that the issue is in the migration, can you share a screenshot of your folder's tree with subfolders, etc.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Class` name is `UpComming` with 2 `m`.

One spelling mistake only.
Give it a try.

Comment: No that did  not fix was not it

Comment: Maybe you can share more details, that would be great.

Comment: Was just about to and it did actually fix it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change class name to ChangeUpcomingEventsView.